# Can you ID this Shimano freehub body?

Tags: shimano, hub, freehub

My LBS can't figure it out and my googling brought up nothing.

The hub itself is Shimano model FH-T3000

[image: back side]

[image: top]

[image: front]

[image: hub]

[image: hub]

It's from a 3yr old, 8spd, $100 wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FH-T3000 is Acera, but only what I have found is that the hub is 8/9/10 speed. No info on 7-speed.

This is the freehub body Y3TD98050

https://tantrumrideco.com/products/freehub-body-shimano-fh-rm66-y3td98050

Comment: You're right, I just realized I have a spacer and 7spd cassette, so it is 8 spd, any idea on the hub body?

Comment: @JimW What does it say on the cassette lockring? That should help you out

Comment: Shimano Hyperglide-c

Comment: Thanks once I realised that my hub body wasn't a 7 spd, I was able to find the answer. https://tantrumrideco.com/products/freehub-body-shimano-fh-rm66-y3td98050